# Wrong output rendering by nested map array in react.js

Tags: reactjs

Iam getting output two time like.OUTPUT::: ****css csss laravel laravel**..**INSted OF **css laravel**. WHy plz help me to Correct this code I have problem in looping .I want to display the checkbox which is check or unchecked for a only one time like css laravel
PLZ GO TO THIS SITE FOR access RUNTIME WORKING CODE https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-dream-dm3c0?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const tate = {
    tags: [
        { id: 1, Tag_name: "laravel" },
        { id: 2, Tag_name: "css" }
    ]
};

const hiding = {
    hide: true
};

export default function App() {

    const [form, setForm] = useState({ tags: [{ id: 1 },{ id: 2 }] });

    const handlecheck = ({ target }) => {

        console.log(target.value);

        setForm((prev) => {

            return prev;
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {

        console.log(form);

    }, [form]);

    return (

        <div className="form-group row">

            <label htmlFor="inputEmail3" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
                TAG


            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
                <div className="checkbox">
                    {tate.tags.map(
                        (tag) =>
                            hiding.hide &&
                            form.tags.map((taged, i) => (
                                <label key={i}>
                                    <input
                                        name="tag[]"
                                        type="checkbox"
                                        value={tag.id}
                                        onChange={handlecheck}
                                        checked={tag.id === taged.id ? true : false}
                                    />
                                    {tag.Tag_name}
                                </label>
                            ))
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: You're mapping over `tate.tags` and within that you're mapping over `form.tags`.

Comment: Plz correct this I know the problem but I TRIED ALOT I CANT go to this link.  https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-dream-dm3c0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, so I can't write your code for you. You *may* be trying to map over `form.tags` and *look up* the tag name in `tate`, in which case, you should just do that instead.

Comment: Iam trying to checked the check box if tag.id°==taged.id  other wise not ...BUT THE OUTPUT IT GIVE SAME EACH VALUE  TWO times plz go to this link u will understand what I meanhttps://codesandbox.io/s/magical-dream-dm3c0?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 loops and each loop has 2 element. So, 2 loops make duplicate. You can check simple fixes here: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-mayer-f65v8

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const tate = {
  tags: [
    { id: 1, Tag_name: "laravel" },
    { id: 2, Tag_name: "css" }
  ]
};

const hiding = {
  hide: true
};

export default function App() {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({ tags: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }] });

  const handlecheck = ({ target }) => {
    const _id = parseInt(target.value);

    const index = form.tags.find((t) => t.id === _id);
    let _form = null;

    if (index === undefined) _form = { tags: [...form.tags, { id: _id }] };
    else _form = { tags: form.tags.filter((t) => t.id !== _id) };

    setForm(_form);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(form);
  }, [form]);

  return (
    <div className="form-group row">
      <label htmlFor="inputEmail3" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
        TAG
      </label>
      <div className="col-sm-10">
        <div className="checkbox">
          {tate.tags.map(
            (tag) =>
              hiding.hide && (
                <label key={tag.id}>
                  <input
                    name="tag[]"
                    type="checkbox"
                    value={tag.id}
                    onChange={handlecheck}
                    checked={
                      form.tags.find((t) => t.id === tag.id) !== undefined
                    }
                  />
                  {tag.Tag_name}
                </label>
              )
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro can I have your fb id so that we can be friends